# Allow access from every subdomain NelmioCorsBundle

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, symfony5, nelmiocorsbundle

On my project, I have a subdomain for every client. I want to set in the `nelmio_cors.yaml` file rule that will allow every subdomain to access my `/api`

In my code I have:

File: `/config/packages/prod/nelmio_cors.yaml`

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: ['https://default.com']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['https://default.com','*.example.com', '^(https?://.+\.example\.com(?::\d{1,5})?)$']
            allow_headers: ['Accept', 'X-Custom-Auth', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'cache-control', 'x-requested-with', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS']
            allow_credentials: true
            max_age: 3600
```

So, I tried as in example `*.example.com` and `^(https?://.+\.example\.com(?::\d{1,5})?)$` but that doesn't work. If I put `*` it works, but then I allowed access from everywhere.

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header only allows `*` as a "blanket" wildcard covering _every_ origin, you can not use it as only a partial wildcard in combination with static parts. You need a dynamic solution, that checks the `Origin` request header's value for whether you want to allow access, and then responds back with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header containing that _exact_ Origin again.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are not supported but origin_regex option are.
This configuration works for me and allow all subdomains of mydomain.com:

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    origin_regex: true
    allow_origin: ['^https://(.+.)?mydomain.com']
    allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
    allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
    expose_headers: ['Link']
    max_age: 3600
paths:
    '^/': null
```